# Laravel 5.5 How to get all models related to model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot, relationships

I have model User that has relationship with itself

```
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'subscription', 'subscriber_id');
}
```

that I made for making users subscribe to each other. I made pivot table 
with 2 columns (subscriber_id, user_id). So on user profile I showed all users that the current user is subscribed to with

```
$user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$subscribed = $user->subscription;
```

And that works. So now I don't know how to show all users that are subscribed to that user? I tried with `DB::table('subscription')->where('user_id', 1)->get();` but that doesn't return the User model. I know it's easy solution but I am really stuck on this one...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over the `$subscribed` collection to get all user's subscribed to that user.

```
$user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$subscribed = $user->subscription;

foreach ($subscribed as  $subscriber) {

    $subscriber->name;
}
```

Comment: Then I get all the users that user is subscribed to, which I already have. I need all the subscribed users to that profile.

Comment: @MilePanic Your question is not clear. Please explain more

Comment: Ok so on user profile page I want to show all users that subscribed to him, and all users that he subscribed to. I wrote how I made a list of users that the profile subscribed to `$user->subscription` which returns the collection of all users that profile subscribed to. Now I need the opposite - list of all users subscribed to that profile. I hope I am more clear now with my problem.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks anyways. ```$query      = DB::table('subscription')->where('user_id', 1)->pluck('subscriber_id')->toArray();
        $subscribed = User::whereIn('id', $query)->paginate(10);```